# How to fix attribute error in Django(Python)?

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie to Python and Django.
I'm watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=2 this course and following instructions.

But there is and error message keeps coming out like this.

```
AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'post_list'

C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\django_project\blog\urls.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\django_project\django_project\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\django_project\blog\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    path('', views.home, name='post_list'),
AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'home'
```

At pylint, they said `Module 'blog.views' has no 'home'`
So I think there is no home function at apps.py but I already call home function like this.

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')
```

blog/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
]
```

django_project/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

blog/apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')
```

I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
path('', views.home, name='post_list')
```

you're saying the view home is in the module `views`, but as you already said, it is in apps.py, hence the error: `Module 'blog.views' has no 'home'`.

Just move your function/view `home` to the blog.views module.

Comment: Remember that if the answer is correct select it and/or up-vote it. That way you'll encourage people to keep helping you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to register your app in the settings file.

You want to look for a list of apps the add your app `blog` to that list.